# Option to add line-markers for all lines in preprocessed file

Tags: c, gcc, clang, preprocessor

I am analysing a preprocessed C file to generate a mapping between the source file line-numbers and preprocessed file line-numbers.

Is there a way to generate the preprocessed file such that it has line markers for all lines in the preprocessed file.

```
 gcc -E  test.c -o test.i
```

This doesnt generate line-markers for all lines.
It only has line-markers for the include lines.
So need to keep track of the last line marker to find the filename and derive the line number.

Is there a better approach than this?

Example:
Test.c Source:

```
1. #include "test.h"
2. #define ADD(x) x + x;
3. 
4. void fun () {
5.    return 10;
6. }
7. int main () {
8.     foo(1);
9.     ADD (10);
10.    return 0;
11. }
```

Test.h Source:

```
1. void foo(int i) {
2.     return i + 10;
3. }
```

Preprocess command:

```
gcc -E test.c -o test.i
```

test.i Source:

```
1. # 1 "test.c"
2. # 1 "<built-in>"
3. # 1 "<command-line>"
4. # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
5. # 1 "<command-line>" 2
6. # 1 "test.c"
7. # 1 "test.h" 1
8. void foo(int i) {
9.     return i + 10;
10 }
11. # 2 "test.c" 2
12. 
13. 
14. void fun () {
15.    return 10;
16. }
17. int main () {
18.     foo(1);
19.     10 + 10;;
20.     return 0;
21. }
```

test.c: Source_line - Preprocessed_line Map

```
{
"4": "14",
"5": "15",
"6": "16",
"7": "17",
"8": "18",
"9": "19",
"10: "20",
"11":"21"
}
```

test.h Source_line - Preprocessed_line Map

```
{
"1": "8",
"2": "9",
"3": "10"
}
```

Comment: *"need to keep track of the last line marker to find the filename and derive the line number"* This sounds very easy. Why not do it?

Comment: Could you show an example of what you would like to obtain from a specific file input ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Checking to see if there is option to directly dump all the linemarkers or is the suggested approach the best

Comment: @PtitXav: Added code snippets with the input and output

Comment: What exactly is your issue with tracking the source file names and line numbers by the lines like `# 2 "test.c" 2`?

Comment: @thebusybee: As mentioned in my previous comment, I'm checking  to see if there is an option to directly have line markers for all lines by the preprocessor.

Comment: Why should the preprocessor provide that information? It will unnecessarily fill up its output and does not contribute any additional information. -- You can easily write a simple script to get what you want.

Comment: got it. The conclusion is that there is currently no such option provided by the preprocessor to dump line markers for all lines in the source code